# How do you simulate Flutter state restoration inside an automated test?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a widget that uses state restoration and does some extra logic in the `restoreState` method. I'd like to test that logic, so I'm wondering if there's a way to trigger state restoration from within a Flutter test.

I can manually test the logic with an Android emulator using "Don't keep activities" which will trigger `restoreState` when the application is restarted, but I want to do it in an automated test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a widget test ([An Introduction to Widget testing](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/widget/introduction)—by Flutter). In the automated test, the Flutter app can be forced to restart and restore its state using the instance method `restartAndRestore()` from the `WidgetTester` class.

For example:

```
testWidgets('Description of the test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(MyWidget());
  // modify the state of the app
  await tester.restartAndRestore(); // restoreState gets called here
  // verify the custom logic in restoreState executed successfully
});
```